# Android Studio: Error:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know that this question was here a lot of tims. I tried all of the solutions. I've got a source code of app. I want to build it but i'm getting this error: **Error:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy**

Here is a part of *build.gradle (Module app)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sensiblewallet"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android.keystore")
            storePassword "123456"
            keyAlias "sensiblewallet"
            keyPassword "123456"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

Here is *build.gradle (Project)*:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I tried everything.. what's going wrong? Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: With a `compileSdkVersion` of 21, I don't think you need `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`. That is not required until you set `compileSdkVersion` to 23 or higher. So, you could just comment out that line. Now, most likely, you *should* set your `compileSdkVersion` to something higher (latest is 25), but doing that, and updating your `buildToolsVersion` to match, may allow that library to load.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use API 23+:

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}
```